# Matlab: finding the maximum point in for loop

Tags: matlab, fminsearch

For two variable function, say **f(x,y)=x^2+y+b**, where **b** is:

```
b=raylrnd(1*sqrt(2/pi),10^6,1)  %% b is 1x1000000 vector
```

and subject to the constraint that: **2*x+1<=b**.

I want to find the maximum of the function for a interval say x is between [-10,10], and y is between [-10,10] (Off course, my actual function is more complete than this, I will need help to set up the framework so I can apply it to my actual function).

Is there a way to implement this?

---

Attempt:

Step 1: Write a file objfun.m.

```
function f = objfun(x,b)
f = x(1)^2+(2)+b;
```

Step 2: Write a file confuneq.m for the nonlinear constraints.

```
function [c, ceq] = confuneq(x)
% Nonlinear inequality constraints
c = 2*x(1)+1-b;
```

Step 3: Invoke constrained optimization routine.

```
for i=1:1:length(b)
bi=b(i);
x0 = [-1,1];            % Make a starting guess at the solution
options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','sqp');
[x,fval] = fmincon(@objfun,x0,[],[],[],[],[],[],... 
   @confuneq,options);
```

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable method. If each solution should be "close" to the next solution (i.e. the next `b`), then you might consider using the previous solution as the `x0` for the next optimisation. That could help make each iteration faster.

Comment: you have a some typos in your suggested code. In objfun it should be `x(2)` and not just `(2)`. Also in the optimization routine the loop is not complete. I'm also quite confident you should store the results somewhere. It also would be great if you would state more precisely with what part of your solution you are not satisfied.